# "Unexpected token {" when using jquery.parsejson()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When I console log my return data it looks like this:

```
returnData = 
"{"requests":[{"region": "NA","message": "test","monster": "For Fun", 
"roomNumber" : "", "password" : "", "HR" : ""}
{"region": "NA","message": "test","monster": "For Fun", "roomNumber" : "",
"password" : "", "HR" : ""}
]}"
```

When I try to `jQuery.parseJSON(returnData)` it return an error of unexpected token {

I am not sure what needs to happen. Any ideas would be great! Thanks

Comment: Huh? That isn't even valid JavaScript... Also, jQuery automatically parses JSON responses for you. You don't need to do that yourself. Tip: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to check JSON validity. And more importantly: Use a proper JSON serializer on the server side, I'm willing to bet that you are currenty building make-believe JSON by concatenating strings. Don't do that.

Comment: seems your json is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
{"region": "NA","message": "test","monster": "For Fun", 
"roomNumber" : "", "password" : "", "HR" : ""}
```

should have a comma after the `}`, in order one object be separated by the other:

```
{"region": "NA","message": "test","monster": "For Fun", "roomNumber" : "",
"password" : "", "HR" : ""}
```

As it is, it is not a valid `json`.

You could check it this, using [this](http://jsonlint.com/) validator. Using this validator for the following JSON

```
 {
    "requests": [
        {
            "region": "NA",
            "message": "test",
            "monster": "For Fun",
            "roomNumber": "",
            "password": "",
            "HR": ""
        },
        {
            "region": "NA",
            "message": "test",
            "monster": "For Fun",
            "roomNumber": "",
            "password": "",
            "HR": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I got that is valid.

Answer (score 1):

there is a "," missing:

```
{"requests": [{
    "region": "NA",
    "message ": "test",
    "monster": "For Fun", 
    "roomNumber": "",
    "password": "", 
    "HR": ""
}, {
    "region": "NA",
    "message": "test",
    "monster": "For Fun",
    "roomNumber": "",
    "password": "",
    "HR": ""
}]}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't even notice. I was missing a comma between my objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid. Try this.

**JSON**

```
{
"requests": [{
        "region": "NA",
        "message": "test",
        "monster": "For Fun",
        "roomNumber": "",
        "password": "",
        "HR": ""
    },
    {
        "region": "NA",
        "message": "test",
        "monster": "For Fun",
        "roomNumber": "",
        "password": "",
        "HR": ""
    }]
}
```

Comment: correct answer but less obvious that it was a comma error